# How to load all gallary images quickly in flutter

Tags: flutter, imagepicker

I want to make a custom image picker in a custom bottom sheet. I did it using [photo_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/photo_manager) package and it works, but it loads images with full resolution, so it is so slow and it gets slower as I scroll down to see more images.
how can I load gallary images into a bottom sheet so fast? (as fast as telegram chat image picker!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a option for thumbnail:

```
Uint8List thumbDataWithSize = await entity.thumbDataWithSize(width,height); //Just like thumbnails, you can specify your own size. unit is px; format is optional support jpg and png.
```

I've used it with 400*400, and it's quite ok